# LINQ to SQL not getting correct data

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Using Studio 2008, C#, SQL Server 2005, Winforms. I've looked all over this site and can't find a situation that is the same...

I have data1 window filled from a LINQ to SQL connection. I click a button to open data2 window and edit data in there. 
When I close data2 window, I need to refresh the data in data1 window. 
So I call the SQL Server with a query through LINQ. I'm not getting back the new data I just saved from data2 window. I'm getting the old data back that was already there.
Any ideas why? I verified that the data was saved in the SQL database and it is there.

Now if I close data1 window and reopen it, the correct data is there. But why when I requery the database right after closing data2 window is the data in data1 window not updating?

Code:

```
IEnumerable<tblConstructionRevision> newRev1 = (from y in DDBML.tblConstructionRevisions orderby y.RevDate descending, y.RevNo descending where y.DrawID == drawID select y);
```

It doesn't matter if I get back FirstOrDefault or the list. I can't return it to a List<> because I need the entire dataset.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers. It was a cache issue. Didn't know that existed but now I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's cached, check this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/07/01/linq-to-sql-tips-9-understanding-datacontext-s-internal-caching.aspx

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. That was a good reading and helped me figure out the problem...it was caching it and now I know how to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [Refresh method of your data context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534217.aspx) to invalidate the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Its sounds like you're keep DDBML around with your form.  I think as long as the context is open it will cache the tracked entities.  You should use the datacontext then dispose if it, and open a new one when you need to.  See this for more about the caching: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/07/01/linq-to-sql-tips-9-understanding-datacontext-s-internal-caching.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the current data, use MergeOption.NoTracking. This means that they are not stored in the graphs that track updates and deletions of entities in the same context. If the data you are reading is already updated in another context, window, or application, this method ensures that the data you read will be up-to-date. It should be noted that disabling object tracking will also prevent you from submitting updates to the database. So after reading, you should put the MergeOption value into the original.

```
System.Data.Objects.MergeOption mergeOption = DDBML.tblConstructionRevisions.MergeOption;
DDBML.tblConstructionRevisions.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;

var newRev1 = (from y in DDBML.tblConstructionRevisions 
     orderby y.RevDate descending, y.RevNo descending
     where y.DrawID == drawID select y);

DDBML.tblConstructionRevisions.MergeOption = mergeOption;
```

Or you can use ExecuteStoreQuery() method, and specify NoTracking in the parameters. The same effect can be achieved.

```
var newRev1=db.ExecuteStoreQuery<tblConstructionRevisions>(
　　 "SELECT * FROM tblConstructionRevisions y WHERE y.DrawID = @ID 
          order by y.RevDate desc, y.RevNo desc",
　　 "tblConstructionRevision",
　　 System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking,
　　 new SqlParameter("@ID", drawID));
```

In Entity Framework 4.1, you can use the new AsNoTracking() method:

```
var newRev1 = (from y in DDBML.tblConstructionRevisions.AsNoTracking() 
     orderby y.RevDate descending, y.RevNo descending
     where y.DrawID == drawID select y);
```

or

```
var newRev1 = (from y in DDBML.tblConstructionRevisions 
     orderby y.RevDate descending, y.RevNo descending
     where y.DrawID == drawID select y).AsNoTracking();
```

**[What NoTracking Does](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/4/2/entity_framework_and_asnotracking)**

*Entity Framework exposes a number of  performance tuning options to help you optimise the performance of your applications. One of these tuning options is .AsNoTracking(). This optimisation allows you to tell Entity Framework not to track the results of a query. This means that Entity Framework performs no additional processing or storage of the entities which are returned by the query. However it also means that you cant update these entities without reattaching them to the tracking graph.*